# INSERT de una imagen .jpg en Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, imagen, insert

Quiero insertar una imagen .jpg en una tabla 'category' que consta de tres columnas: id_category de tipo integer, category_name de tipo text y category_image de tipo bytea.

He intentado hacerlo con la siguiente instrucción ...

```
INSERT INTO category
VALUES(3, 'Tercera categoría', bytea('F:\2. PERSONAL\Pictures\islaprincipal.jpg'))
```

... obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
ERROR:  sintaxis de entrada no válida para tipo bytea
LINE 2: VALUES(3, 'Tercera categoría', bytea('F:\2. PERSONAL\Picture...
                                             ^
Estado SQL: 22P02
Caracter: 59
```

¿Alguien sabe qué error estoy cometiendo?

Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Siempre se recomienda usar rutas y no guardar archivos en la DB, crees que sea mejor?

Comment: Siempre es aconsejable primero mover el archivo a subir hacia una carpeta en el servidor,  luego cuando la imagen ya este subida realizar el INSERT teniendo en cuenta la ruta,  ya que lo ideal siempre es NO tener imagenes subidas a una base de datos como tal,  si no mas bien tener la ruta de la imagen subida a la base de datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Roberth y Riven. En este caso particular me gustaría guardar las imágenes en la propia BD.

Comment: Un archivo no se carga de esa manera pues el campo aunque guarda binarios no tiene la lógica para entender lo que estás queriendo hacer, para almacenar archivos debes usar las funciones para [SQL-Oriented Large Object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/lo-funcs.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes escapar el contenido de `bytea` usando `pg_escape_bytea` despues de leer los contenidos del fichero de imagen con `file_get_contents`:

```sql
INSERT INTO category
VALUES(3, 'Tercera categoría', pg_escape_bytea(file_get_contents('F:\2. PERSONAL\Pictures\islaprincipal.jpg')));
```

Y luego la puedes leer añadiendo el prefijo de base64:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('data:image/png;base64,',encode(category_image, 'base64')) AS category_image 
FROM category
```

Comment: Una respuesta con puro código no es útil: no explica, no enseña. Tal vez le sea útil al OP, pero a nadie más.